# Error: expected identifier before 'template'

Tags: c++, class, templates, composition

I'm working on an assignment for an introductory C++ course and am trying to make the compiler happy, but everything I've done so far throws some sort of error.  An error is being thrown with the following code:

```
friend void make_LinkedList(template <class T>LinkedList<T> &list, node *root);
```

This is inside the definition of the class tree which has a private struct node.  LinkedList is a templated class.  This function is meant to convert a tree to a linked list.  Basically, I need to have the function accept a node pointer and a LinkedList object as arguments.  LinkedList is templated, though, and I can neither find nor figure out the syntax for defining a function that accepts a templated class object that's defined in a different header file.  Please let me know if I've left anything out.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: The "template <class T>" part applies to the function, not its parameter. You're declaring a template for a function, with the templated parameter. Either `template class <T> friend void make_LinkedList(LinkedList<T> &list, node *root);` or simply `template class <T> friend void make_LinkedList(T &list, node *root);`. Not possible to authoritatively state, without a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the `template <class T>` before the method definition:

```
template <class T>
friend void make_LinkedList(LinkedList<T> &list, node *root);
```

Comment: I would add: A class template is not a type; it's a family of types. You can't define a single function that takes a templated parameter; what you have to do is to define a family of functions (a function template).

Comment: Thank you for your help!